# adding pcl library with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, point-cloud-library

I am trying to add pcl into a QT project with qmake. I found a lot of posts with the same problem, but no solution that helps me.

I am working on a mac and installed pcl with homebrew. So all my libraries are found under "usr/local/Cellar/"

I tried to add some libraries with pkg configuration

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += eigen3
```

I also tried it with different packages.

After that I added the Libraries manually:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/1.8.0_2/lib
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/pcl/1.8.0_2/include/pcl-1.8/pcl
```

The Library got added. But when I wanted to include  he is searching for pcl/PCLHeader.h which is included as PCLHeader.h.

Is there a way to add all the libraries to pcl/ ? The same problems come with every library I tried to add.

And is there no way to simply use the flags: PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have qmake. You seem to be in the right direction in your usage of LIBS and INCLUDEPATH.

Try removing the **/path** from the end of the **INCLUDEPATH**. That will let qmake/compiler see the pcl/PCLHeader.h file.

Answer (score 0):

for me :

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += eigen3

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/pcl-1.8
```

and them (for example) in cpp or hpp:

```
 #include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the PCL 1.7 binaries installed from apt on Ubuntu 16.04. The configuration that worked for me was this:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += eigen3
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/pcl-1.7
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpcl_common -lpcl_filters -lpcl_sample_consensus
```

I had to add the individual libraries that I wanted to use. I'm adding this as an answer in case anybody else needs it.